# Problem with remove function while trying to remove a file from directory in C++

Tags: c++

I need to remove a file from a directory based on the input of user and pass it into a function that perform the file remover process

```
/* Class 3 veus 3:45PM*/
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>

void remove_file(std::string file);

int main() {
  std::string file_name;
  std::cin >> file_name;
  remove_file(file_name);
}

void remove_file(std::string file) {
     if(remove("C:\\MAIN_LOC\\" + file + ".txt") == 0) {
        std::cout << "`" << file << "`" << " Item deleted successfully" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "[Error] File not found";
  }
}
```

Ok now the thing is I got several error on `remove` function: `function "remove" cannot be called with the given argument list`. I'm not sure what the error mean so I'd like for an explanation.

Comment: As a side note, stdio.h and cstdio are the same thing and it's highly recommended to use cstdio in C++ instead of stdio.h.

Comment: Another side note: if possible, you should prefer to use the stuff from `<filesystem>` instead of `<cstdio>`

Comment: The error message will certainly have more to say than just "cannot be called with the given argument list". I am pretty sure it will contain at least the parameter type declared for the function (`const char *`), and the argument type you actually called the function with (something along the lines of `std::basic_string<char>`)...

Comment: @perivesta Is `<filesystem>` built-in header or I need to install it? because it throws "cannot open source file 'filesystem'".

Comment: @PythonicUser It became standard with C++17, so you need a halfway current compiler. If you can't update, check if your compiler has an option to enable C++17 support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the function with c string instead:

```
void remove_file(std::string file)
{
     std::string x = "C:\\MAIN_LOC\\" + file + ".txt";
     if(remove(x.c_str()) == 0)
     {
        ....
}
```

Comment: When there's problem.. there's always slovakian man to brighten your day

Answer (score 5):

`remove` takes a C string, but your expression `"C:\\MAIN_LOC\\" + file + ".txt"` is a C++ string. Use the `c_str` method to convert to a C string

```
remove(("C:\\MAIN_LOC\\" + file + ".txt").c_str())
```